# How does - (void) translate in swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift, function, game-center

I came across this code on apple documentation on how to implement Game Center achievements. But I don't quite understand what "- (void)" really mean and how I can use it in a class.

```
- (void) challengeViewController:(MyAchievementChallengeViewController*)controller wasDismissedWithChallenge:(BOOL)issued
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    if (issued)
    {
        [controller.achievement issueChallengeToPlayers:controller.players message:controller.message];
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me the use of keyword void in this context?

Comment: The next step is to find out what does `void *` mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the function has no return value.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the function is in front of the function name in Objective-C. So `(void)` is the return type.

So the Obj-C `- (void) myFunc` is equivalent in Swift to `func myFunc() -> Void` or the `-> Void` can simply be omitted to get `func myFunc()`.

That function would translate to

```
func challengeViewController( _ controller: MyAchievementChallengeViewController, wasDismissedWithChallenge challenge: Bool) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Dávid it makes sense to me now. I just started learning Swift and and SwiftUI and I have been struggling with apple docs. This helps.